# How to run flex mobile application in background?

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

I need to run my android application (written in Flex) in the system background, so that periodically performs some defined task. Unfortunately I can not find any hints on the Internet:( I would also like to know how such an application to restore from the system background?

Please help if you know the solution.
Thank you.

Best,
Martin

Answer (score 3):

> I need to run my android application (written in Flex) in the system
>   background, so that periodically performs some defined task

Technically you should be able to minimized it on launch; however for performance issues non active applications are throttled.  That means everything--including timers--will run slower than expected.  So, 1 second on your timer will not necessarily equal 1 second in the real world when the application is inactive.

Unless it will be okay for the user to manually trigger your tasks; you should consider an alternate technology for the implementation.  AIR is just not usually suitable for background applications.